# Manage domain name purchased through azure

Tags: azure

I purchased a custom domain name through Azure, and it was correctly pointing to my Web App, and it was working. I subsequently deleted and recreated the Web app, and the underlying IP has changed. In order to associate the same domain name with the replacement app, Azure requires the CNAME to be set by the DNS provider. However, Azure is the DNS provider, and I can find no way to do this. I see lots of articles discussing how to manage the domain name once it is associated with the app, but not how do to manage it the gap between creation and association, which is the gap where I need to add the CNAME.

Comment: In this [Azure doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/) It is specifically mentioned that domains purchased through Azure cannot be managed with GoDaddy, even though GoDaddy hosts the zone. There is a reference to a "Manage Domain" blade within Azure specifically for managing these domains. But I can't find it. I must be blind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because the subscription was changed from a pay-as-you-go subscription to developer benefits subscription. The purchase of the domain name is tied to the subscription with it was purchased. Creating the App under the original subscription enables the management blade.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/10/01/mapping-a-sub-domain-to-an-azure-web-site.aspx

and this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/

Edit: Also, you could do what you are asking for through **Powershell**: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/dns-web-sites-custom-domain/

Comment: The first two, not applicable. Using Powershell, That may be a possibility. I'll need to research further on that.

Comment: Can't do this via PowerShell either.

Comment: The Azure commands only allow manipulation of an Azure DNS zone. The zone is hosted by GoDaddy, but because of the agreement between godaddy and Microsoft for domains purchased through azure, Microsoft is responsible for their management. Godaddy will not do any management.

Answer (score 0):

Did this recently, using "myfunkydomain.com" and "myfunkywebapp" as examples ..

1. Bought the domain through Azure ("Custom domain and SSL" blade on the WebApp) which you have already done.
2. The new "DNS preview" service allows you to create DNS Zones and then manage the subdomain recordsets - Create a new zone (I called "myfunkydomain.com" and take note of the 4 DNS servers allocated to the zone.
3. Then under "Custom domain and SSL" blade of your Web App select the new domain (myfunkydomain.com) under "Managed Domains" and then click the Advanced menu button - this will take you to a seperate site where you can delegate the domain to the 4 DNS servers from step 2.  This is what you are missing I think.  I took note of the current DNS servers before changing them (but have had no need to change them back)
4. Once delegated you can create CNAME recordsets under the DNS preview Zone and point the CNAME record to the full domain of your Web App myfunkywebapp.azurewebsites.net and you are in full control of the domain from the Azure portal.  There is a WebApi for managing this whole process which we use to create new tenants of our domain programatically.